# Flutter screen that contains a scrollable and clickable tiles at the left side of the screen in drawable

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a screen in flutter/dart that has three horizontal lines at the top left corner of the screen and when clicked on it, it displays a list of clickable texts, when clicked on it, it has to take to the next page. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListTile and ListView widgets are used to represent a tile as a list in flutter and Drawer widget is the horizontal lines things that you are talking about, i suppose.

Here is the sample code for it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<HomePage> {
  bool _value1 = false;
  bool _value2 = false;

  void _onChanged1(bool value) => setState(() => _value1 = value);
  void _onChanged2(bool value) => setState(() => _value2 = value);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(

      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF293b72),
        title: new Text('Hughes InstaGrade'),
      ),
      drawer: new Drawer(
          child: new ListView(
            children: <Widget> [
              //new DrawerHeader(child: new Text(''),),
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Home'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => HomePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('New Dull Grade'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => FirstForm(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              //new Divider(),
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Search'),
                onTap: () {

                },
              ),
              //new Divider(),
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Filter'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => FilterPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Forms'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => Forms(title: "Forms"), 

                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
        new SwitchListTile(
          value: _value2,
          onChanged: _onChanged2,
          title: new Text('My Bits/All Bits', ),
        ),

              new ListTile(
                title: new Text('Log Out'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => LoginPage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
       // new Switch(value: _value1, onChanged: _onChanged1),

            ],
          )
      ),
      body: DataScreen(),
    );
  }

}

String _formatDate(String date) {
    DateTime d = DateTime.parse(date);
    return DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(d);
  }
}

class DataScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Data Screen"),
      ),
      body: Text("Sample App"),),
    );
  }
}
```